# Looping through list of PRs using GitHub CLI?

Tags: bash, github, grep, github-cli

I'm looking for advice on how to approach a certain scripting problem using GitHub CLI. Let's say I used the `gh search prs "SPARK-" --match body` command to get a list of all prs with the body containing the SPARK- phrase. Now, I want to loop through that list of prs, and output the url of that pr along with it's SPARK number (somewhere in the body of the pr, there is text saying "SPARK-" followed by a unique 5 digit number). Any ideas on how to approach this? I'm having difficulty figuring how I might be able to construct this loop using my gh cli output (or if it's even possible?), let's say in some bash script, and figuring out how to specifically isolate the SPARK number.

Comment: What in particular are you having a hard time with? The output of `gh search prs ...` provides output that is relatively easy to parse with `awk` to extract repository names and pr numbers, for example (and you can ask for the specific metadata using the `--json` option).

Comment: This needs the [tag:github-cli] tag, not the [tag:git-cli] tag, and it's specific to GitHub so [tag:git] is not really appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do everything in one `gh` invocation:

```sh
gh search prs "SPARK-" --match body --json url,body --jq '
    "SPARK-([[:digit:]]+)" as $re
    | map(select(.body | test($re)))
    | .[].body |= match($re).captures[0].string
    | map([.url, .body])[]
    | @csv'
```

The `--json` parameter selects URL and the description, and `--jq` massages the JSON into a comma-separated list (see [jq playground](https://jqplay.org/s/aXv4fP0sNL)):

```
"https://github.com/just4jc/CSE6242-Data-and-Visual-Analytics/pull/32","1298180"
"https://github.com/h950059h/kafka-examples/pull/33","1298180"
"https://github.com/terrorizer1980/zeppelin/pull/75","2420837"
"https://github.com/muyenzo/reference-architectures/pull/10","574943"
"https://github.com/microsoft/az-python/pull/461","35714"
"https://github.com/radanalyticsio/streaming-amqp/pull/38","1298181"
"https://github.com/orysmudi/tensorflow/pull/78","573164"
"https://github.com/apache/iceberg/pull/4479","30669"
"https://github.com/alonsoir/strata-2016/pull/17","1298180"
```

The jq command first defines a regular expression `SPARK-([[:digit:]]+)`, then uses it to drop all PRs where `SPARK` is found, but not followed by digits; then it replaces the body with the capture group of the first match of the regex, returning just the number.

Finally, it rearranges into arrays and converts to CSV.

Comment: Followup to this response: I just realized sometimes there can be multiple SPARK numbers. I know captures[0].string returns the first match but what if I didn't know how many matches there are? How would I access them all? Is captures just like an array that I can call the length of?

Comment: @DuaaZaheer You could use the `"g"` flag to get all regex matches, and then repeat the URL for each match, something like [here](https://jqplay.org/s/Yd3LLDx1kA) (though that can almost certainly be written much more concisely).